# Can I use last N blocks of AES-CBC +IV as hash?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Suppose I want to take advantage of hardware accelerated symmetric encryption like AES and use it to compute a “hash”. How collision resistant would it be if I’d take the IV + last N blocks of an AES CBC transformation and use it as my hash. What would be good
Values for N?

In my hypothetical use case I am not immediately concerned about adversarial inputs / pre image attacks.

Comment: The [SPHINCS+](http://sphincs.org/resources.html) hash-based digital signature scheme has a variant that uses Haraka as the underlaying hash function, which can be computed using AES-NI CPU instructions. It's mostly suited for short inputs.

Comment: If you fix the IV and assuming, inputs are prefix free, CBC is considered a PRF. So the last block is a kind of hash. But I don't know by heart the security bound for input length limits

Comment: @MarcIlunga A PRF doesn't give a hash. It gives a MAC, but it doesn't say anything about the ability to generate collisions if you know the key.

Comment: The question is somewhat underspecified and not sure we should assume a secret key and that the "hashes" are more like "unique" fingerprints or not.

Comment: @MarcIlunga you're right - I wasn't too much concerned about adversarial inputs, I was more after: "is this file/data the same as that other file/data and can I use hardware acceleration for this".

Comment: @DannyNiu SPHINCS+ is quite interesting for this purpose, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't use the last block or even the last blocks of CBC encryption as a cryptographic hash. What you describe is a slight generalization of [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). CBC-MAC is a one-time authentication code: an adversary who does not have the secret key, and does not have access to authentication tags from distinct messages with the same IV, cannot forge an authentication tag for a new message. CBC-MAC can be made into an actual MAC (not requiring an IV) with a slight modification, with [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) being a popular standard. However, both for CBC-MAC and CMAC, anyone who knows the secret key can construct collisions.

Consider a block cipher $E$, an IV $\mathrm{IV}$ and a message $P_1||P_2||\ldots$ (cut into blocks for the block cipher). The CBC accumulator calculation after processing the first two plaintext block is $E(E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P_1) \oplus P_2)$. Let $P'_1$ be any block value:

$$E(E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P_1) \oplus P_2) = E(E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P'_1) \oplus E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P'_1) \oplus E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P_1) \oplus P_2)$$

Let $P'_2 = E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P'_1) \oplus E(\mathrm{IV} \oplus P_1) \oplus P_2$: the messages $P_1||P_2||\ldots$ and $P'_1||P'_2||\ldots$ will have the same CBC accumulator, and thus the same hash. This shows that it's possible to construct collisions for any message that's large enough.

It is possible to construct a hash function generally from a block cipher, but you can't just use the block cipher in CBC mode. A popular technique is to [construct a one-way compression function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Construction_from_block_ciphers) and use the [Merkle-Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) to build a hash on top of that. At least with this approach, [you can't just run the block cipher once per input block](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/223).

There are several well-established generic ways to construct a one-way compression function and thus a hash on top of a block cipher: [Davies-Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer), [Matyas-Meyer-Oseas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Matyas%E2%80%93Meyer%E2%80%93Oseas), [Miyaguchi–Preneel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Miyaguchi%E2%80%93Preneel), [Hirose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Hirose), [MDC-2 and MDC-4](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4908861A/en)... I'm not familiar with all the constructions and their respective security properties and performance. The only one that I'm aware of that has an established standard is Matyas-Meyer-Oseas (MMO), which is used in [a deprecated method to prepare passwords for PBKDF2 in EAP-PSK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4764.html#appendix-A) and in [Zigbee (§B.6)](https://zigbeealliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/docs-05-3474-21-0csg-zigbee-specification.pdf) (where it's used with HMAC as well).

Comment: Why is CBC-MAC a one time MAC?

Comment: @MarcIlunga Because it's possible to forge collisions by extending a message with a known MAC. It can be used as a MAC if there's an additional constraint that all valid messages must have the same length, or (I think) if the message encodes its own length in a sufficiently unforgeable way (in a fixed-size mandatory header).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thank you for the detailed explanation! I'll mark the answer as accepted but I'd like to also thank others who commented